# custom data type in c: 4x14bit + 1x8bit within a 64 bit 'container'

Tags: c, linux, types, embedded

i am currently trying to figure out an elegant and convinient way to store 4 14-bit values and 1 8-bit value within a 64 bit boundary.

something like this:

```
typedef struct my64bit{
    unsigned data1 : 14;
    unsigned data2 : 14;
    unsigned data3 : 14;
    unsigned data4 : 14;
    unsigned other : 8;
}tmy64Bit;
```

later I wan't to create an array of these 'containers'

```
tmy64Bit myArray[1000];
```

so that i have a pointer "myArray" wich points to 1000x64-bits of memory

this array is send via tcp to an embedded-linux SOCFPGA system where it should be copied (with correction of endianess and network byte order) into a specific memory (directly accessible from the fpga)

my problem is that the upper code doesn't create a 64-bit type

```
sizeof(tmy64Bit)
```

returns 12, so 12 bytes are allocated instead of 8

filling the struct with data and watching the memory (on my 64 bit linux system) returns this

```
tmy64Bit test;
memset(&test,0,sizeof(tmy64Bit));
test.data1 = 0x3fff;
...
test.other = 0xAA;

Memory View:
after d1 written = 0xFF3F0000 00000000 00000000
after d2 written = 0xFFFFFF0F 00000000 00000000
after d3 written = 0xFFFFFF0F FF3F0000 00000000
after d4 written = 0xFFFFFF0F FFFFFF0F 00000000
after o  written = 0xFFFFFF0F FFFFFF0F AA000000
```

so the first 2 14 bit variables are stored correctly but then padding fills up the last half-byte and at the end the last byte needs to be stored in a new 64 bit cell

an other aproach would be

```
typedef struct my2nd64Bit{
 uint8_t data[7];
 uint8_t other;
}tmy2nd64Bit;
```

where a

```
sizeof(tmy2nd64Bit)
```

returns an 8 (which was expected)

This generates correctly padded structure, but storing the 14 bit always involves a lot of bitshifting and masking

Comment: There is no layout specified for bitfield-structs. Use `uint64_t` and bitops to assemble a 64 bit value, then properly serialise to an `uint8_t []` using shifts. (they exist under the hood anyway.

Comment: "so that i have a pointer "myArray" " - `myArray` is an **array**! An array is not a pointer.

Comment: In case your compiler supports something like GCC's __attribute__((packed)) you could be lucky using that. Otherwise, C does not guarantee bitfield packing and you should refer to the method Olaf pointed out.

Comment: Just write functions to serialize from / deserialize to `struct myStruct{uint16_t data[4]; uint8_t other}`.  Using bitfields will cause the compiler to generate pretty ugly code anyway so its not likely to be a performance improvement over doing the packing/unpacking yourself.

Comment: @tofro: `packed` also does not guarantee the expected layout. Not sure if it even works on bitfield struct`s. It also breaks the ABI if not used with caution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want :

```
typedef struct my64bit{
    uint64_t data1 : 14;
    uint64_t data2 : 14;
    uint64_t data3 : 14;
    uint64_t data4 : 14;
    uint64_t other : 8;
}tmy64Bit;
```

`unsigned` means `unsigned int`, and this type is 32-bit on most systems. This will cause padding because the individual fields won't be allowed to cross 32-bit boundaries. Using a 64-bit member type won't add padding for this case (you don't cross any 64-bit boundary).

As for any question about bit-fields, you need to remember that most of the bit-field mechanics are implementation defined, which means that if you want to use that, you should check that you actually get what you want. Also, if you plan to use another compiler, check that the behavior is the same (usually it is, but maybe not on exotic platforms). If you properly check, this is safe to use (not undefined behavior), but you might want to use a more portable way, using bit operations for example.

Comment: This code is no improvement. The alignment of such bit-field members is unspecified (we can't know it). We can't know if `uint64_t` is an allowed bit-field type - impl.defined behavior. We can't know if the fields are allowed to cross boundaries - impl.defined behavior. We can't know if or where there will be padding bytes - unspecified behavior. We can't know if there will be padding bits. We can't know the bit order, implementation-defined behavior. And so on. Add endianess on top of that. Just throw away all crap code like this and instead write safe, deterministic, portable code.

Comment: @Lundin I already wrote that this is not portable. The fact is, it will most likely work on most platforms. There is nothing inherently wrong with writing non-portable code. Surprisingly many "big" software are made non-portable. And the sad truth is, it is actually quite hard to write real portable code. Even your answer is non-portable.

Comment: Hi, this is working for me on both platforms (Endianess is different but this is ok)

Comment: There _is_ something inherently wrong with non-portable code and that is blocking yourself from code re-usage in future projects. Particularly in embedded systems, where porting snippets/source files/libraries of code between all kinds of exotic systems is common practice. Why would you write non-portable code when there is a portable alternative though? And just because something is "big", it is not necessarily well-written. Just look at the Linux kernel. As for my answer, it should be portable to all sane systems, if you just omit the uint64_t.

Comment: @Lundin I think this is just a matter of compromises. I wrote some inter-MCU protocols, and found that bit-fields are actually less error prone than bitops, because it is much clearer. You can compromise that by using a portable bitops lib, but I found that if you don't write it in assembly, compilers write monsters instead of using bit instructions available on most MCU (bit-fields do use them). This is a bit awkward on the small MCUs. Bitfields make everything simple, clear, and fast, and you can write some cost-less static assertion to check the portability.

Comment: @Lundin About your answer, I definitely think it is sane, but it is not strictly portable. The union will invoke UB. The `uint64_t` is one thing, but more importantly, `uint8_t` may not be defined. `char` is not guaranteed to be 8-bit. Some DSP have a `char` larger than 8-bit. To be strict you should use `unsigned char` and `CHAR_BITS`. Again, I do think your answer is ok, you just have to define what is sane and what isn't. You think that `uint8_t` is sane, and I think bit-fields are sane if you know what you do.

Comment: @ElderBug That's exactly what I mean with "sane" systems. You'll have to assume that `uint8_t` exists and that it gets treated like `char` when it comes to aliasing rules. Systems where either of these requirements don't hold, will not be able to use most C libraries. Using some of the more obscure, obsolete DSPs where bytes are not 8 bits, is a bad idea in general. Writing the code for such a weird device in C sounds like a very bad idea in particular.

Comment: @Lundin Well, I do think, like you, that it is sane to assume that `char` is 8-bit. On some other question on SO I pointed out the exact same thing, but I was told that you should never assume. Apparently some TI DSP still currently sold doesn't use 8-bit `char` (it seems to be true). Whatever. The world is not a sane place. Oh, and I like bitfields.

Comment: @ElderBug Those TI DSPs will have source code written 100% in assembler anyhow, so I don't see why C portability to/from them would be a concern anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid bit-fields, they are so poorly defined by the C standard that they can barely be used in practice. Your bit-field struct code contains something around 5 to 10 different forms of poorly-specified behavior. C standard bit-fields is a dangerous and superfluous feature, simple as that.

Instead, simply use a raw array of binary values, something like this:

```
typedef union {
  uint8_t   array [sizeof(uint64_t)];
  uint64_t  val64;
}tmy64Bit;
```

(Note that the uint64_t in the union will be endianess-dependent)

The de facto way to set and clear bits in such a raw array is:

```
void set_bit (tmy64Bit* x, size_t bit)
{
  x->array [bit / 8] |= 1 << (bit % 8);
}

void clear_bit (tmy64Bit* x, size_t bit)
{
  x->array [bit / 8] &= ~(1 << (bit % 8));
}
```

Or if you will, a more readable version (equivalent):

```
void set_bit (tmy64Bit* x, size_t bit)
{
  uint8_t byte_index = bit / 8;
  uint8_t bit_index  = bit % 8;

  x->array[byte_index] |= 1 << bit_index;
}
```

Comment: +1. bitfields in C are o.k. if you do not need any specific layout but just want efficient storage. If you do need it, better avoid them. You'll probably need endianess correction anyway, so there is no benefit from "nicer names".

Comment: @mfro The only type you can safely store inside them is a collection of boolean flags. So "efficient storage" isn't much of an argument, especially not in standard C which has the `_Bool` type for that.

Comment: I was thinking about a set type of single bits. If you don't care about a specific layout, the bitfield is safe to use for this purpose. And much more memory-efficient than an array of _Bool.

Comment: @mfro Single bits in bit-fields are actually pretty dangerous, for two reasons. You could goof up signedness, in which case they invoke UB. And you could goof up implicit type promotions, in which case they could also invoke UB. As for an array of `_Bool`, the compiler is free to implement that as a collection of bits.

Comment: @Lundin: "As for an array of _Bool, the compiler is free to implement that as a collection of bits." - Sure about this? That would break the `sizeof(char) == 1` requirement. Imo `_Bool` has to be at least the same as `char`. Or do you mean non-dynamically indexable bits?

Comment: Just a personal note: When it comes to bitshift, I generally prefer to use `unsigned` integers (`1U << ...`). This is not necessary here, but I think it is good practice.

Comment: @Olaf The only requirement, as far as I know, is that 6.2.5/2 "An object declared as type _Bool is large enough to store the values 0 and 1". Oddly, the standard doesn't seem to specify what will happen when you do `sizeof(_Bool)`.

Comment: @Lundin: According to 6.2.6.1p2 it has to be represented by at least one byte (it is for ARM, e.g.). I don't see an exception for `_Bool`. Old 8051 (and possible other CPU) compilers deviated from that requirement to utilise the bit-addressing features of the CPU, but that was definitively not standard compliant (they couldn't anyway because the MCU could not support the required environmental limits).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Lundin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35725048/5977581), but for this particular situation, my implementation would be a bit different (no pun).

First, I would decide how to pack the fields into each 64-bit word. For example:

```
 Bits    Description
 0-13    data[0]
14-27    data[1]
28-41    data[2]
42-55    data[3]
56-64    other
```

Second, I would use a dynamically allocated structure with the FPGA data in a C99 flexible array member, to describe the target device:

```
typedef struct {
    /* Other FPGA-related fields, maybe
     * a struct sockaddr_in or _in6
     * to identify the FPGA */
    size_t   words;
    uint64_t word[];
} fpga;

fpga *fpga_create(const size_t words)
{
    fpga *f;

    f = malloc(sizeof (fpga) + word * sizeof(f->word[0]));
    if (!f)
        return NULL;

    f->words = words;
    memset(f->word, 0, f->words * sizeof (f->word[0]));        

    return f;
}
```

Third, I would use `static inline` accessors to manipulate the data:

```
static inline unsigned int fpga_get_data(const fpga *f, const int w, const int i)
{
    assert(f != NULL);
    assert(w >= 0 && (size_t)w < f->words);
    assert(i >= 0 && i < 4);

    return (f->word[(size_t)w] >> (i * 14)) & 0x3FFFU;
}

static inline unsigned int fpga_get_other(const fpga *f, const int w)
{
    assert(f != NULL);
    assert(w >= 0 && (size_t)w < f->words);

    return (f->word[(size_t)w] >> 56) & 0xFFU;
}

static inline void fpga_set_data(const fpga *f, const int w, const int i,
                                 const unsigned int value)
{
    assert(f != NULL);
    assert(w >= 0 && (size_t)w < f->words);
    assert(i >= 0 && i < 4);

    f->word[(size_t)w] = (f->word[(size_t)w] & (~(0x3FFFU << (i*14))))
                       | ((value & 0x3FFFU) << (i*14));
}

static inline void fpga_set_other(const fpga *f, const int w, const unsigned int value)
{
    assert(f != NULL);
    assert(w >= 0 && (size_t)w < f->words);

    f->word[(size_t)w] = (f->word[(size_t)w] & (uint64_t)0x00FFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL)
                       | ((value & 0xFFU) << 56);
}
```

Above, `w` is the index to the word, and `i` is the index of the data entry (0 to 3). If you want a continuous `data` array, you could use

```
static inline unsigned int fpga_get_data(const fpga *f, const int i)
{
    assert(f != NULL);
    assert(i >= 0 && (size_t)i < 4 * f->words);

    return (f->word[(size_t)i / 4] >> ((i & 3) * 14)) & 0x3FFFU;
}



    if (f != NULL &&
        i >= 0 && i < (size_t)4 * f->words)
        return (f->word[(size_t)i / 4] >> ((i & 3) * 14)) & 0x3FFFU;
    else
        return 0U; /* Or abort with an error */
}

static inline void fpga_set_data(const fpga *f, const int i, const unsigned int value)
{
    assert(f != NULL);
    assert(i >= 0 && (size_t)i / 4 < f->words);

    f->word[(size_t)i / 4] = (f->word[(size_t)i / 4] & (~(0x3FFFU << ((i & 3) * 14))))
                           | ((value & 0x3FFFU) << ((i & 3) * 14));
}
```

The accessors should be defined in the header file that defines the structure.

Note that if `other` is actually some sort of checksum for the four `data` fields, I would calculate them just before sending.

Comment: I will give this a try, looks clean and useable. The 8 bit for 'other' is actually no checksum. I will run a hashing function over the whole array(s) and append the sum at the end. Thanks!

Comment: @bobTheBuilder: If you want better advice, you might consider adding to your question whether you'd prefer `data` to be accessed as a single one-dimensional array, as a two-dimensional array, or whether the four elements within each word are actually completely separate (and just happen to all be 14-bit). My main point is that this accessor interface should **support** humans -- you and others -- writing and maintaining the code, and thus use your **logical** view of the data. So, describing your logical view of the data in a bit more detail, matters a lot.

Comment: Every element of the 4 14-bit data structures is different (The 64bit structure represents one row consisting of 5 columns within a matrix). They should be filled with information on the host system, send over network to the target system with corrected byteorder (if necessary). The Target should only transfer the incoming serialized data into a seperate ram wich can be accesed by the fpga and the embedded arm processor.